# Two months to go on my masters programme and I want to drop out what should I do?

Tags: masters

I've been struggling with my MSc in political science since the start of the programme. The programme isn't what I expected. And I did a undergraduate degree in finance and already hold an offer from a top financial services firm. I now have two months to finish my dissertation and I want to quit.

I hated my programme with a passion. and I had 0 political knowledge before I applied so I've been struggling since day 1. I've already failed two modules which I'll have to resit after November. I failed because I didn't understand the content. These two modules were about advanced quantitative research and EU politics. And I jumped in with no foundamental knowledge whatsoever. Moreover, with work and professional exams which I will have to study for, I won't have time to study for the resits.

I also hate my dissertation topic. I addressed this issue with my two supervisors but they didn't seem to think it was a concern. Again I came up with the topic with very little background knowledge and without knowing it's actually not something I'd like to do.

I've been trying to re concentrate on my dissertation for a week with no success. The more I read for my dissertation, the more I dislike it.

I've already contacted my firm and my school to discuss any potential consequences of dropping out and I'm still waiting for a response. I don't want to quit but I struggle to continue. It's affected my life severely and I have pre existing depression for years which my school knows about. 
Please give me advice

Comment: You should know that everyone passes through hard times, you should focus more on establishing an equilibrium with yourself-this can be done on many approaches, yoga, sport (I recommend climbing, snowboard, ski-this can also be done in the summer on the grass, these are personal favorites). Concerning your dissertation, can't you changed it with something you really like? I am sure that you can find something related. Nowadays, many approaches are used. I too in my first year undergraduate passed through a similar feelings, but I stayed in the program and I one of the best students inthegroup.

Answer (score 3):

My heart goes out to you, it sounds like you're really unhappy with your current situation and feeling very conflicted.

It's hard to give someone advice on a topic like this because it's so personal so instead I'll give you a few of the questions that I might ask if we were able to sit down and have a chat about this.

1. What initially led you to apply into this masters? Is it your specific experience that is creating problems or is it that this masters does not align with your interests/goals?
2. What is the appeal of this job offer? Can you really see yourself doing that kind of work or is it that it represents a face-saving alternative to completing your masters?
3. What would have to change for you to be comfortable completing your program? Is it a change of dissertation topic? Is it extending by a term or a year to take the pressure off? Changing supervisors? All of the above?
4. Are there jobs that you want, now or in the future, that you can't have without this degree? How important are they to you?
5. Do you really hate your program/subject or do you hate the situation you are in?

Think on these on these until you hear back from your school and your potential employer. Once you have answers to them, take a break and step away from it for a little while; when you come back to it see if you still feel the same way about your answers or if your thoughts have changed.

There's no right or wrong way to do this - I personally trudged through a degree when I knew it wasn't right for me because I was so close to the finish line. Finishing that degree proved to me that I could see something through to completion (something I had always struggled with) but also kept me from finding my true path for another year. I'm still not sure what the right choice was, but I'm happy with where I am now.